# The detail view of a UISplitViewController takes full screen only on iOS8

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

My UISplitViewController was functioning properly until I compiled the project with the new SDK (iOS 8.0). At some point (when the (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated of the detail view controller is called) the detail view maximizes to the full screen, covering the master view.

I managed to fix it by using the new displayMode property of the UISplitViewController:

```
[self.splitViewController setPreferredDisplayMode:UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible];
```

However this property is supported only in iOS8 and now I cannot build for iOS7. Is my only choice now is to download the old SDK?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your app was running okay on iOS 7.1, so (happily) you only need to execute that code in versions of iOS that do support it.  So what about:

```
if ([self.splitViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreferredDisplayMode:)]) {
[self.splitViewController setPreferredDisplayMode:UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible];
```

}

Compile with the new SDKs, and be able to run in old and new iOS. You then just need to set your build Deployment Targets appropriately.

*Hope this helps.*